# Is SQL Server Installation 2008 Express reliable enough to replace MS Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have tried to install SQL Server Express 2008 on several pcs of different brands. I have no luck or what: nearly each time I get something which prevents it from installing.

Just now I got "Performance counter registry hive consistency check" failed and solution is overwelmingly complex http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956.

How can one choose SQL Server Express 2008 as a local pc database vs MS Access as a good choice for selling an application knowing that clients risk to encounter such unsolvable problem for most of them as they are not even expert users ?

Why do so many people push for SQL Server ? Is it really objective ?

As a User myself, I have downloaded many softwares which uses SQL Server Express 2008, since I can't install, I just gave up, I won't even complain because I fear most often they wouldn't even bother (and registering for support is always a hassle). That is companies are losing potential clients without even knowing it !

Comment: The company I work for distributes our application with SQL Server Express 2008, and I do not remember hearing about any problems with it..

Comment: Well I have downloaded many softwares which uses SQL Server Express 2008, since I can't install, I just gave up, I won't even complain because I know most often they wouldn't even bother. That is companies are losing potential clients without even knowing it !

Comment: Most SQL express installs I've done have been fine.  Is there something those PCs all share in common?  Perhaps some domain policies pushed from your security/server team?

Comment: So what's your problem with using Access to store data in the first place?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've installed SQL Server Express a few times and never encountered anything like the kind of problems you describe. Are you running the insaller with full adminstrative permissions? Are you in a domain environment that possibly has some exotic and restrictive group policies in place?

Comment: I've found that Access isn't reliable enough.. and I never have had any trouble with SQL Server.  Have you thought about learning more about SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a local database that you can distribute with your application, do you really need the full-blown SQL Server Express, which needs to be installed?

I think an embedded database (SQL Server CE, SQLite...) is what you need.
They don't require any installation at all, you just have to distribute a few assemblies with your application.

Comment: Yes good remark but MS Access format is as free, there's no install and User can use MS Access Office if they want to, so I can't see why I would use SQL Server CE or SQLite ?

Comment: Access is not free.  You are requiring your customer to buy the office suite to use your tool.

Comment: Sam, if all you are doing is using Access, actually Jet or ACE, to store data then that comes with the Windows since Win 2000.

Comment: @user310291: I'm not sure if I understand what you actually want to achieve. Your original question sounds as if you WANT to replace Access (because you ask if SQL Express is an alternative to it), and now you say you can't see why someone would want to replace Access.

Comment: Actually, Jet 4 comes with Windows. The ACE does not.

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQL Server 2008 installer again and complete these steps.

1. I exported the 009 tree with regedit to Perflib.reg
2. Opened the Perflib.reg in Notepad
3. Replaced "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009]" to "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\013]"
4. Save the file
5. Finally double click the Perflib.reg file.

This should work, [you can find more here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/205bd261-79d2-4b16-803a-f46f092c4e51/)